# How do I backup my site w/o the command line?

Tags: backups

Nearly all the documentation on backing up my Drupal site seems to require using the command line.  My hosting service does not provide command line access.  How do I backup my site without using the command line?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I'd go with the [Backup and Migrate](http://drupal.org/project/backup_migrate) module. You can either start backups manually or have it run automatically on cron run. Then you can just download your `/sites/` folder and you should have a full backup of everything (assuming your files, modules and themes are all in `/sites/` like they should be.)

Comment: This is the must-have module of almost all Drupal sites.

Comment: Why isn't it part of Core?

Answer (score 11):

The "Backup and Migrate" module should do the trick:

http://drupal.org/project/backup_migrate

If you don't want to go that route, you should be able to do a SQL dump of your database (assuming you have a mySQL Admin type interface with your hosting account) and FTP the contents of your Drupal "sites" folder.

That should be enough to restore it elsewhere I'd think.

Answer (score 9):

Another recommendation for Backup and Migrate, and you can also add the [Backup and Migrate Files Module](https://drupal.org/project/backup_migrate_files) if you want to grab your files automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I use [this handy script](http://drupal.org/node/59370) which backups not only the database but the whole site altogether. By adding the DB password to the script, you will be ablt put it in your cron table to makes backups automatically and even add other commands to send the backup to an external server etc.